# Changing the 2nd ,3rd,4th occurrence of a number with other numbers

Tags: python, list, loops, replace, counter

a=[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,7,7,1,2,1,2,0,7,1]
In this list I want to change the value of 1 to 2,3,4,5 etc starting from 2nd occurrence of 1. Let the first occurrence of 1 remain as it is. I have written a program which is given below but it changes the first '1' also. how to instruct it to change from 2nd occurrence and not from 1st occurrence. Can we use counter or something?

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,7,7,1,2,1,2,0,7,1]
change=2
b=[]
for i in a:
    if i!=1:
        b.append(i)
    elif i==1:
        b.append(change)
        change+=1
print(b)
```

Comment: What *should* this print when it is done correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try starting with `change=1`. Right now, you are starting at 2, so the first 1 it encounters will be changed to 2. If you start at 1 instead, then the first will be "changed" to 1, and then the rest should fall into place accordingly

Comment: What if it is from 3rd occourence?

Comment: do you mean you want to let the first and second occurrence stay as 1, but start updating the third occurrence with 2, fourth occurrence with 3, etc?

Answer (score 0):

you should try this instead

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,7,7,1,2,1,2,0,7,1]
countOnes=1
b = []
for i in a:
    if i==1:
        b.append(countOnes)
        countOnes+=1
    else:
        b.append(i)
        
print(b)
```

Comment: What if it is from 3rd occurrence?

Comment: You have to add one if condition before "countOnes+=1" see the code in the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,7,7,1,2,1,2,0,7,1]
countOnes=1
b = []
for i in a:
    if i==1:
        if countOnes > 3:
            b.append(countOnes)
        else:
            b.append(1)
        countOnes+=1
    else:
        b.append(i)
        
print(b)
```